# Selenium RC not running on Firefox 9

Tags: firefox, selenium

The test cases (created in Robotframework and using Selenium RC) that I can successfully run in firefox 3.6 could not be run in firefox 9. It seems Selenium RC is not supporting Firefox 9. Can someone confirm this? What are the options that I have for my tests to run in Firefox 9, is this a mere change of settings in Firefox?

Note: When I run my tests in Firefox 9, upon opening of the page I get a message "Will you help improve Mozilla Firefox" and a white page in the browser. It does not seem to load.

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of selenium are you using?

Comment: the version i am using is v2.0 [b1]

Comment: That doesn't support FF 9.0. You should use the latest version of selenium

Comment: Thanks updated selenium webdriver and it worked with ff9.

Answer (score 0):

Latest selenium-webdriver (2.18) works with Firefox 9.0.1 for me. The problem that I had was that I didn't have X11 forwarding between my development VM and host Mac.